# Xeon E5 1600 v3 family - dual cpu

Tags: cpu, hardware-rec, xeon

I want to build a multi cpu workstation, and I have never built multi cpu computer before.

I wonder if the E5 1600 v3 family support multi cpu setups or if I should use the E5 2600 v3 family instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this generation's Xeons, the first digit in the *Product Family* section of the processor model/SKU number (i.e.: 16xx, or 24xx) tells you how many processors can be used on one motherboard/node (aka "Wayness"; as in 1-way (single CPU), 2-way (dual CPU), 4-way (quad CPU) or 8-way (octa CPU) physical-CPU multi-processing).

[From Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers-data-center.html):

[image]

So to answer your question specifically: No, the 1600 series can't be used in a multi-CPU configuration.